# Getting null parsing an img with jsoup

Tags: android, parsing, image, jsoup

I am having a problem parsing this html:

```
    <div class="big-photo report-photo"> 
    <img alt="Europa" src="/media/asset_publics/resources/000/004/121/news_landscape/europa.jpg?1339265409" />
```

and my code:

```
    Element img = doc.select("div[class=big-photo report-photo] img").first();
```

I connect succesfully jsoup with the html but the img is null, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I solved it using a DIV above "big-photo report-photo"

Comment: If its solved, please post your solution as an answer and **accept** it.

Answer (score 0):

Add `String url = img.attr("src");` after your code. Good luck

Comment: Not sure if this answers the question; anyway, please provide some explanation...

Comment: `doc.select("div[class=big-photo report-photo] img").first()` this code return element like `<img... src=...>`. So now if you want to get the value of attribute `src` use `.attr("src")`. More information you can fetch by reading the [method summary](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#attr-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-). 

Hope it's helped you.